# User get signed out after signing in - When clicking another link

Tags: asp.net, login-control, loginview

I have created a web application where i want users to register Login , log out, etc.

For now, I have created a custom CreateUserWizard, that guide the user through the registration process.

My web application contains several aspx pages , as Login , Register, ,Services and the Default.

When the user visits the site, he is presented with the Default.aspx page where there he sees an horizontal navigation bar with three links: Home (takes again to the Default.aspx), Services(takes to the Services.aspx page where the user see his services) and  the Login In link (ASP Login control) that takes the user to the Login Page.

The content of the Default.aspx page that the users see the first time he visits the page, is again a registration form.

Now, i can register succesfully a new user, and his credentials are stored in the Membership database, and also i can log in a registerd user.

After the user is successfully logged in, he is directed to the Services.aspx page.

**The problem is that when he gets to the Services.aspx page after logging in, and click on a link in the horizontal navigation bar, the user is automatically logged out.**

**Ιn the Web.config file in the *authentication* tag, in the *forms* section I have set it to not use cookies, but instead use *cookiless="UseUri"* .**

**I did this because if i use cookies, when the user logs in, then the LoginView control doesn't display the LoggedinTemplate, that is  name of the user that logged in, and keeps showing the message of AnonymousTemplate.**

I don't understand why is this happening, but i am guessing that it has to do something with the not using cookies fact. Anyone has any idea of what might be the problem?

**Below i provide the code of the Default.aspx page where the wizard for registration is and also the Web.config file.**

**PLEASE POINT ME TO THE RIGHT DIRECTION OR WHAT AM I DOING WRONG HERE.

**Default.aspx** :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"


   MasterPageFile="~/GDesk.Master"
        CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="GDesk._Default" %>

        <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/styles.css" />
        </asp:Content>
        <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <h2>
            Welcome </h2>
        <div id="SignUpForm">
            <h2 class="defaultH2">
                Sing Up</h2>
            <p class="info">
                Here you can register. If you already have an account, please log in
    <asp:HyperLink ID="defaultLogin" runat="server"       NavigateUrl="/Account/Login.aspx"
                    Text="here." />
                <span class="important">Passwords are required to be in minimum of
                    <%=Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength()%>
                    characters.</span>
            </p>
            <span class="failureNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="errorMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
            <p>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ErrorSummary" runat="server" 
               ShowSummary="true"   CssClass="failureNotification"
               ValidationGroup="RegisterMessages" />
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="CheckErrors" runat="server" 
               ShowSummary="true" CssClass="failureNotification"
               ValidationGroup="CheckExistence" />
    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" 
             runat="server" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="Services.aspx"  
             AutoGeneratePassword="false" 
               EnableViewState="true" MailDefinition-BodyFileName="~/MailFile.txt"
                    MailDefinition-From="psf89@yahoo.com" LoginCreatedUser="true">
       <WizardSteps>

          <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUser" runat="server"   
           EnableViewState="true">
               <ContentTemplate>
                  <fieldset class="register">
                    <legend>Account Information</legend>
                      <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text="Username:" AssociatedControlID="UserName" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" 
                        CausesValidation="true" CssClass="userEntry"
                        ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" 
                         runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                        ErrorMessage="Username required" 
                        CssClass="failureNotification" ToolTip="UserName is required"
                        Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"        
                        ValidationGroup="RegisterMessages">*
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                     </p>
                     <p>
                       <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server"    Text="Email:" 
                        AssociatedControlID="Email" />
                       <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" 
                       CssClass="userEntry" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
                       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" 
                       ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="Email Required"  
                       CssClass="failureNotification" ToolTip="Email is required"
                       Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"  
                       ValidationGroup="RegisterMessages">*  
                       </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                       <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="EmailTypeRequired" 
                       runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                       SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+
                       ([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                       ValidationGroup="RegisterMessages" Display="Dynamic" 
                        CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Give a valid 
                        email" ToolTip="Give a valid email form">*
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </p>
                                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text="Password:" AssociatedControlID="Password" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server"       
                        CausesValidation="true" CssClass="userEntry"  
                         TextMode="Password" />
                       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" 
                        ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password Required"
                        runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" ToolTip="Password 
                        is required" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"    
                       ValidationGroup="RegisterMessages">* 
                       </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="confirmPasswordLabel" 
runat="server" Text="Confirm Password:" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword" />
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" 
runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="userEntry"
                                                TextMode="Password" />
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                                                ErrorMessage="Confirm Password  
required" 
CssClass="failureNotification" ToolTip="Confirm password is required"
                                            Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" 
ValidationGroup="RegisterMessages">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="ComparePasswords" 
runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password"
                                                ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password and Confirmation Password must 
match"
                                                Display="Dynamic" Text="*" 
ValidationGroup="RegisterMessages">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="SecurityQuestionLabel" 
runat="server" Text="Security Question:" AssociatedControlID="Question" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="Question" runat="server" CssClass="userEntry" 
 CausesValidation="true">
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="--Select one--" 
Value="" />
                                                <asp:ListItem>What is your mother's 
birthday ?</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>What was your first dog's 
name ?</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>What was your favorite 
teacher's name ?</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>What is your favorite 
 actor's 
name ?</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <br />
                                        <i>In case you forget your password you will be 
asked to answer one of the security
                                                questions you choose here and prompted 
to 
enter the answer you specify below.</i>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
ID="SecurityQuestionRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Question"
                                                ErrorMessage="Please select a security 
question" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="failureNotification"
                                                ToolTip="You must select a security 
question in case you forget your password"
                                                SetFocusOnError="true" 
ValidationGroup="RegisterMessages">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</p>
<p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="SecurityAnswer" runat="server" 
AssociatedControlID="Answer" Text="Security Answer:" />
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="true" CssClass="userEntry" />
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
ID="SecurityAnswerRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Answer"
ErrorMessage="Please provite an answer to  the above question" Display="Dynamic"
ToolTip="This is the answer to the question 
you selected above" CssClass="failureNotification"
SetFocusOnError="true" 
ValidationGroup="RegisterMessages">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      </p>
   </fieldset>
</ContentTemplate>
<CustomNavigationTemplate>
                                <p class="ButtonSubmit">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Previous" runat="server" 
Text="Previous" CommandName="MovePrevious" />
                                        <asp:Button ID="CreateUserButton" 
 runat="server" 
Text="Create User" ValidationGroup="RegisterMessages"
                                            CommandName="MoveNext" />
                                    </p>
                                </CustomNavigationTemplate>
                            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                            <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteRegistration" 
runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <span class="UserCreatedNotification">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="SuccessMessage" runat="server" 
Text="User Registered Succesfully !" />
                                </span>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <CustomNavigationTemplate>
                                <p class="ButtonCompletedReg">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Continue" runat="server" 
 Text="Continue" CommandName="Continue" />
                                </p>
                            </CustomNavigationTemplate>
                        </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
                    </WizardSteps>
                </asp:CreateUserWizard>
        </div>
        <div id="VideoPresentation">
            <h2 class="defaultH2">
                Presentation Videoh3</h2>
            <h3>
                Under Constraction...</h3>
        </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

**And here is the Web.config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyLocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data 
    Source=THESAINT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UserAuthentication;Integrated  
    Security=SSPI;"/>
  </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" 
        />

        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="/Account/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" protection="All" 
            timeout="30" path="/FormsAuth" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" 
       defaultUrl="Default.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" 
       enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
        </authentication>

        <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
          <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
connectionStringName="MyLocalSqlServer" applicationName="GDesk" 
enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                    enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                    minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
          </providers>
        </membership>

        <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
          <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>   
    </system.web>

  <location path="Services.aspx" >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>     
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

**Thank you in advance !!!**

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use cookieless!!!  It's very insecure.
2. If you do use cookieless, use relative URLs to navigate within the site.  It's possible that your users are getting logged out because the link to Services.aspx uses an absolute URL that does not of course contain the session ID.
3. If you're having trouble with cookies, it might be because your login form is not in the root of the web site.  In this case the cookie will be set with a path that makes the cookie invisible to parts of the site that aren't in the same folder.  To get around this, either move the login form or explicitly set the path of the forms authentication cookie to "/"